# Text Mate double quote a selection?

Tags: textmate

is there an easy way within TextMate that I can select a string, hit some key and magically it will surround the string with double quotes.

For example:

```
 I have some text here
```

I select this text, use some command sequence and I have:

```
 "I have some text here"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure! once you have selected the text, the key is "

Comment: give me the big "duh" award, I tried 10 different combinations of things, but never the obvious

Comment: interesting this works for single and double quotes, but not for parens and brackets.

Comment: There's a chapter about this in the manual: http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text.html#auto-paired_characters_quotes_etc

Answer (score 3):

Handy extra tip: don't miss Ctrl-Shift-' (that is, Ctrl-") to toggle the quotes surrounding the cursor from single to double quotes.